# How to remove a preference from PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android

I'm using PreferenceActivity. How do I remove a preference? I cannot seem to get this to work:

```
Preference p = findPreference("grok");
boolean worked = getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(p);
// worked == false.
```

So the preference is found, but the removePreference() call fails. What's the right way to do this? I'm using a preference.xml file for the keys like so:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="foo">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="grok" />

            ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can remove only exact child in PreferenceGroup. So in your case, you should add some key to PreferenceCategory (with title="foo"), then findPreference with this key & then remove it child

XML:

```
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="category_foo"
    android:title="foo">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="grok" />

        ...
```

Code:

```
Preference p = findPreference("grok");
// removing Preference
((PreferenceGroup) findPreference("category_foo")).removePreference(p);
```

Comment: I'm curious, why does it work while you specify a PreferenceCategory in the XML but the cast it to a PreferenceGroup in the java? The code works either way, it just seems confusing.

Comment: @marienke it works, because `PreferenceCategory` is direct subclass of `PreferenceGroup`, so it's mean that `PreferenceCategory` is `PreferenceGroup`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceCategory.html

Answer (score 4):

Instead of setting multiple ids, you can get the entire tree of preferences and find the parent of any preference, and then remove any of its children preferences:

```
public static Map<Preference,PreferenceGroup> buildPreferenceParentTree(final PreferenceActivity activity)
    {
    final Map<Preference,PreferenceGroup> result=new HashMap<Preference,PreferenceGroup>();
    final Stack<PreferenceGroup> curParents=new Stack<PreferenceGroup>();
    curParents.add(activity.getPreferenceScreen());
    while(!curParents.isEmpty())
      {
      final PreferenceGroup parent=curParents.pop();
      final int childCount=parent.getPreferenceCount();
      for(int i=0;i<childCount;++i)
        {
        final Preference child=parent.getPreference(i);
        result.put(child,parent);
        if(child instanceof PreferenceGroup)
          curParents.push((PreferenceGroup)child);
        }
      }
    return result;
    }
```

example:

```
  final Map<Preference,PreferenceGroup> preferenceParentTree=buildPreferenceParentTree(SettingsActivity.this);
  final PreferenceGroup preferenceParent=preferenceParentTree.get(preferenceToRemove);
  preferenceGroup.removePreference(preferenceToRemove);
```

---

EDIT: seems there is a new API for this :

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference#setVisible(boolean)

I'm not sure if currently it's available or not, though.