# How to link to a specific preferencegroup

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

**BACKGROUND:**
I have a preference.xml with 3 preference groups, call them GroupA, GroupB and GroupC, each of which have a number of items.  I can start my options intent, and it shows my 3 groups, clicking on each group gives the sub items.  This works just fine.

When I start the preferences intent from my main activity, I can pass some extra information as follows.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Options.class);
intent.putExtra("pg","GroupB");
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the Options class, onCreate routine, read the extra information like this:

```
String sPrefGroup = intent.getStringExtra("scr");
```

**QUESTION:**
How do I instruct the Options class to display the selected PreferenceGroup, rather than starting at the root of the Preferences XML

Comment: I think you can remove the two others group. Something like in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4754139/857728

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but then GroupB shows and I still need to click on that to see the items in that group.  I was hoping to simulate the selection of the preferencegroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution was to make a copy of the preferences.xml file, called preferences_groupb.xml which only contained the preference items I wanted to display

Then in the Options.class I used code similar to the following:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String sPrefGroup = intent.getStringExtra("pgGroupB");
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sPrefGroup))
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
else
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_favorites);
```